# Strategies for handling recurring homework questions

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, subjective, homework

Every now and again, you get a homework question that recurs. The question itself varies, but it's the same poster and the same code snippets and there really doesn't seem to be any progress being made. Sometimes the question being asked seems to have been answered several times already.

Other than ignoring these things and moving on, what general strategies would you suggest in this situation.

For an example, consider...

- [help with set & map on STL for c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322748/help-with-set-map-on-stl-for-c)
- [crash - adding to a map and set STL - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361223/crash-adding-to-a-map-and-set-stl-c)
- [adding to a set STL - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367891/adding-to-a-set-stl-c)
- [STL set not adding properly c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394061/stl-set-not-adding-properly-c)
- [Memory Leaks - STL sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394529/memory-leaks-stl-sets)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404795/47-memory-leaks-stl-pointers

Comment: Maybe he suffers from short term memory loss....

Comment: This is another example of OP behaviour that led me to ask 'Does SO get abused by helpdesks' in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88699/does-so-get-abused-by-helpdesks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close as duplicates (if you have the mojo), comment about what you are doing and why, and (since it seem to be persisting) bring it to the attention of the moderators.

Comment: I think I lack that mojo, but I'll keep this in mind for the next time.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and would add that your question isn't specific about homework - you can vote to close duplicates anytime a question is duplicate (and you're aware of it), regardless of its tags and content.